# How to supress a column/row from a table to print it

Tags: r

I need to print some tables. Something like that:

```
>print(tab)

   D    D1    D2    NA
A                     
A1   0.447 0.289   NaN
A2   0.419 0.611   NaN
A3   0.101 0.058   NaN
NA   0.032 0.041   NaN
```

Only a few data have `NA` values​​. The table was created like this:

```
tab<-table(now.and.fathers,useNA="ifany").
```

I need to print it without the column/row `NA`.

Comment: How to *suppress* sorry!!

Comment: What does it mean to say: "I'll need the data with NA, but I just wanna print without the column/row NA Thanks."??? Doing a print or table operation does not destroy any data. And by the way there is no English verb spelled "wanna". To many of us it looks like infantile speech.

Answer (score 0):

I must be missing something, but here is a mock data frame (not a table)

```
structure(list(D1 = c(0.447, 0.419, 0.101, 0.32), D2 = c(0.289, 
0.611, 58, 0.041), Null = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "NA", class = "factor")), .Names = c("D1", 
"D2", "Null"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

And you can index whatever rows and columns you want:

```
print(df)[1:3, 1:2] # omits right NA column and bottom NA row.
```